# Wrap container around inline divs

Tags: css

Here is my problem. I have inline-block divs inside another div.

```css
.timeEvents {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.events1, .events2 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.ev1, .ev3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.ev2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.mDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeEvents">
  <div class="events1">
    <div class="ev1">Data Field 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="ev2">
      <div class="mDiv">5</div>
      <div class="mDiv">10</div>
      <div class="mDiv">15</div>
      <div class="mDiv">20</div>
      <div class="mDiv">25</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="events2">
    <div class="ev3">Data Field 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `.ev2` to be wrapped around its children which are inline. Then, the two data fields, respectively `.ev1` and `.ev3` placed above and below, should have the same width as `.ev2`. Which means that all divs with a red border (in my JSFiddle) should have the same width (dynamic, I don't know it) and that width should not be 100% as it's in the jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/mzjqw2wx/17/.

EDIT - I updated my fiddle. I don't want to lose the outside 100% divs, I want to align the three red sections to have the same width, the page and the outside divs all remain 100%. The tip to use inline-block on the wrapper was great, it did what I wanted with the middle one. I wanted to align all red containers and I did it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also set `display: inline-block;` for the common wrapper (and give `text-align: center` to its parent)

```
body { text-align: center; }

.timeEvents {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzjqw2wx/5/)

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: This has been the most useful tip so far! But as I further clarified the problem, I don't want to lose the outside divs set to 100%. I need to align the events divs, so to say.

Comment: add another block wrapper between your body and .timeEvents (or inside .timeEvents as immediate children)

Comment: I did it with jQuery, I don't know if it was the easier solution. I updated my fiddle, you can see the final result. The other tips were very nice as well, perhaps I didn't state quite clearly what I meant. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy to implement using [Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Just assign `display: flex;` to `.ev2` and `flex-grow: 1;` to the the `.myDiv` class.

You can see it in the following code:

```css
.timeEvents {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.events1, .events2 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.ev1, .ev3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.ev2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}
.mDiv {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeEvents">
  <div class="events1">
    <div class="ev1">Data Field 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="ev2">
      <div class="mDiv">5</div>
      <div class="mDiv">10</div>
      <div class="mDiv">15</div>
      <div class="mDiv">20</div>
      <div class="mDiv">25</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="events2">
    <div class="ev3">Data Field 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out [CSS-Trick's Complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table` to `timeEvents` and remove `width:100%` will make as per your expected.

```
.timeEvents {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzjqw2wx/10/)**